# PDIST does not accept complex data for built-in distances

Tags: matlab, distance

I got an error beside this line of code:

```
done=pdist([a;a1],'minkowski')>=m;
```

where `a` and `a1` are two matrices of the same size.

The error was:

```
Error using pdist (line 144)
PDIST does not accept complex data for built-in distances.
```

What does that mean? How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*"What does it mean?"*

It means: **PDIST does not accept complex data**

*"How can I solve this issue?"*

Just take the real part:

```
done = pdist( real([a;a1]),'minkowski')>=m;
```

or the absolute values:

```
done = pdist( abs([a;a1]),'minkowski')>=m;
```

But the point is, **you should know that you get complex data** and how to proceed with it, **before** you use `pdist`.